# JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application from java -jar myprogram.jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, java-module

I know that this has been asked multiple times, but i cant fix this problem with the `--module-path="<path of javafx lib> --add-modules=javafx.controls, etc...` solution. I have openjdk version 11.0.7 and javac 11.0.7.

I have Intellij and my javafx program runs well from intellij. But i cant run the executable .jar file, and when i try tu run it from my terminal with `java -jar myprogram.jar` it throws the
***JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application*** error.

This is my module-info.java
[module-info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xHsH.png)

this is the .jar that i im trying to open
[program.jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThwZR.png)

Again. In my intellij the program works perfectly. But when i try to open it from the .jar executable doesnt work, and when i try it with `java -jar myprogram.jar` it throws the error [JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFhOx.png)

Comment: See https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX.

Comment: Try this https://alexiyorlov.github.io/tutorials/install-javafx.html and then tell where are you failing.